Primefaces Media-Component not working using StreamedContent
I am trying to use Primefaces p:media component in Version 13.0.5 to display PDF´s loaded from database.
This is my BackingBean getter and it's definitely being invoked and building the StreamedContent with the provided byte[] from the database:
public StreamedContent getMedia() {
    StreamedContent result;
    if (this.selectedRow == null) {
        return null;
    }
    result = DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
            .contentType("application/pdf")
            .stream(() -> {
                try {
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(this.getSelectedDokument().getDocumentAsByte());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .build();
    return result;
}

and this is my xhtml-code:
   <div class="card">
      <h5>PDF</h5>
         <p:media value="#{controller.getMedia()}" width="100%" height="590px" id="media" cache="false"
           player="pdf"/>
   </div>

When using a static path to PDF in the resources-folder it´s working fine.
Tested it with Primefaces Extensions (Version 13.0.13) pe:documentViewer too and behavior is the same, but getting the following error(s) in the browser console.

Can anyone guess what is going wrong here?

Is your bean @RequestScoped like in the Showcase stream example?

My Bean ist SessionScoped. I just found a solution for this problem. In my xhtml-files I define vars like this:
<c:set var="seiteMB" value="#{freiwilligeMB}"/>
when using "seiteMB" the p:media component won´t work with streamedContent.
"freiwilligeMB" is doing fine. I don´t really get it, but it works. But thank you very much for responding.

ahh can you please try adding a .name("my.pdf") value and see if it works.
result = DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
            .contentType("application/pdf")
            .name("my.pdf")
            .stream(() -> {
                try {
                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(this.getSelectedDokument().getDocumentAsByte());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .build();


No, wont´help. Already tried.

Can you put together a PF Test reproducer: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test  ???  I think your issue may be similar to this one: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/13064

When passing a ValueExpression with a StreamedContent to a composite component, there are some limitations:

reusing a variable from JSTL (e.g. <c:set ... />)
passing a partial expression. you should pass the whole ValueExpression via cc.attrs (cc.attrs.streamedContent vs cc.attrs.myBean.streamedContent)
using MethodExpressions

I adjusted the PF 15.0.0 docs for it.
